# MVC Multiple Models in one view using a parent model

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to add a second model to my index page(contains 2 partial views as a two column page) following the "Passing Multiple Models using ViewModel" section of this page: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Using-Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-M

Ive created a model to hold the other 2 called MasterModel which is where i wish to store my other models

```
public class MasterModel
{
    public UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
    public LogDataServerDBEntities LogDataServerDBEntities { get; set; }
}
```

In my Index, _NewRequest _ExistingRequest pages i changed the model from

```
@model IEnumerable<TMTMonitorandCompare.Models.UserInfo>
```

to

```
@model IEnumerable<TMTMonitorandCompare.Models.MasterModel>
```

and changed my data display to be "Model.UserInfo"

```
 @if (Model.UserInfo != null)
 {
   foreach (var item in Model.UserInfo)
      {
          <tr>
             <td>
             <input type="checkbox" class="checks">
             </td>

             <td class="modal2row" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#basicModal3">
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreationDateTime)
             </td>

             <td class="modal2row" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#basicModal3">
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppModeId)
             </td>

         </tr>
       }
 }
```

ControllerMethod:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string filtername)
    {
        var filterresults = from m in db.UserInfoes
                            select m;

        filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.UserCode.ToString().Contains(filtername)).OrderBy(x => x.UserCode);
        CheckDownloaded();
        PopulateViewbag();

        return View(filterresults);
    }
```

Only now i get the error :

Error   1   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'UserInfo' and no extension method 'UserInfo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Can anyone Explain to me where /with what I am going wrong ??

Comment: could you please post the controller code, and show how you are constructing the model object(MasterModel)

Comment: Not sure this may be an issue, but as a practice,it is not adviceable to use the same class name as property name [public UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }]

Comment: @Baggerz, I have rolled back your edit - you cant change the question completely. Just add the code I requested in the comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UserInfo` is an object in `MasterModel` (not a collection). I suspect what you want is

```
public class MasterModel
{
  public List<UserInfo> UserInfo { get; set; }
  ....
}
```

and in the main view

```
@model TMTMonitorandCompare.Models.MasterModel
```

then you can use

```
foreach (var item in Model.UserInfo)
{
  ....
```

**Edit**

Based on additional information from OP, the action method needs to be changed to match the model

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string filtername)
{
  var filterresults = from m in db.UserInfoes select m;
  filterresults = filterresults.Where(x => x.UserCode.ToString().Contains(filtername)).OrderBy(x => x.UserCode);
  ....
  MasterModel model = new MasterModel();
  model.UserInfo = filterresults;
  // set other properties of model as required
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Stephan, after making the change above the errors in visual studio disappear. I also changed the partial views to have the same @model statement, but I then get this error when running the solution: 

System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[TMTMonitorandCompare.Models.UserInfo]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TMTMonitorandCompare.Models.MasterModel'.

Comment: Edit your question to include the controller method - you don't appear to be passing the correct object to the view - it should be something like `MasterModel model = new MasterModel(); model.UserInfo = someCollection; return View(model);`

Comment: I don't have that in my code, Ive posed my index method above.

Comment: I'll update my answer to address the additional problem

Comment: Thanks again Stephen you really are a star of Stack Overflow. Ive updated my code with your changes however I got the error Ive added in my edit. I think this is because of List<UserInfo> so i changed it to IEnumerable<UserInfo> which solved the errors and all is working :)

Comment: @Baggerz, Sorry about that. `IEnumerable` is fine in your case, although if you wanted `List` (e.g. to use a `for` loop) you could have added `.ToList()` to the end of the query.